# Wrapping issues in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, word-wrap

I am trying to prevent IE from breaking a string texts from within words and instead break a string only from white spaces (blank spaces). So I don't want works split into two parts like what happened to word "users" in the image below

[image]

[image]

I listed the styling here. please let me know what to do so that "Active many users" break from blank spaces only?

Comment: Remove the `word-break: break-all;` from your CSS. The default behaviour is to break on white space. You are telling the browser to do the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: @SexyTurnip removed it but did not see any changes

Comment: @SexyTurnip thanks for the tips.I fixed it by removing all of these three: -ms-word-break: break-all,word-break: break-all and -ms-hyphens: auto;